# Strange DNS host name response

Tags: domain-name-system, dig

I've recently experienced an XML-RPC attack vs wordpress from a pair of machines for which dig -x returns a very very odd looking result:

```
;; ANSWER SECTION:
54.249.96.191.in-addr.arpa. 60  IN  PTR DEDICATED.SERVER.
```

I've never seen a TLD named DEDICATED before. I get the same result from my home machine and within amazon...

Comment: In this case, `SERVER` is the TLD, not `DEDICATED`.

Comment: If you're looking to find the responsible party for this IP, `whois` will be more useful.

Comment: Why the downvote? Is my question unclear somehow?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no actual requirement that PTR records return valid host names.

<sub>Unfortunately.</sub>

---

The typical approach to find the owner or ISP that manages an IP-address (range) is a [WHOIS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WHOIS) lookup.

In this case the  191.96.249/24 range is managed by company called Dmzhost Limited with `abuse AT DMZHOST.CO` as their email contact.

Comment: So DNS has a built in "cloak me" mechanism... fabulous.

Comment: whois wasn't installed, but now it is. Previously I had assume dig would be reliable :) thx

Comment: @Gus DNS has no such thing.

Answer (score 0):

The guy who runs those servers (chris@dmzhost.co) is as dodgy as they come, and he allows his servers to be used for DDoS:

https://medium.com/@alek.boyd/plunging-into-a-ddos-hole-a-how-to-guide-b7565f814513#.s97ens0gl

Comment: I realise your username is a fairly big clue, but you might want to make the fact you are the author of that post clearer (see e.g. https://serverfault.com/help/promotion) - and extend your answer a little to reflect the contents of both your medium post, and the post you made on your own blog.